# Compiler error C : "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm running 3 simple C files
**area.h**

```
//
//  area.h
//  modular
//
//  Created by Fryt Os on 14/01/2024.
//

#ifndef area_h
#define area_h

#include <stdio.h>

double areaRectangle(double width, double height);

#endif /* area_h */
```

**area.c**

```
//
//  area.c
//  modular
//
//  Created by Fryt Os on 14/01/2024.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include "area.h"

double areaRectangle(double width, double height){
    return width * height;
}
```

**main.c**

```
//
//  main.c
//  modular
//
//  Created by Fryt Os on 14/01/2024.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include "area.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double width = 4;
    double height = 2;
    double area = areaRectangle(width, height);
    printf("The area of the %fx%f (width x height) rectangle is %f\n", width, height, area);
    return 0;
}
```

But when trying to run the files, i get the following error by the compiler :

```
frytos@MBP newModular % cd "/Users/frytos/code/newModular/" && gcc main.c -o main && "/Users/frytos/code/newModular/"main
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _areaRectangle, referenced from:
      _main in main-87d40c.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Environment**

I'm running on MacOs Sonoma 14.2.1, with Visual Studio Code
The extensions installed are C/C++ Extension Pack, CMake, CMake Tools, and Code Runner

**CLang**

```
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I tried to find related issues, but only founded ones related to XCode.

So I tried running the same 3 files in XCode, and it worked perfectly...

Can someone help me understanding what's failing when working from VS Code, and how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot community !

I tried to find related issues, but only founded ones related to XCode.

So I tried running the same 3 files in XCode, and it worked perfectly...

Can someone help me understanding what's failing when working from VS Code, and how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot community !

Comment: The problem is that the default code-runner plugin only builds one single source file. You need to use the full Microsoft C and C++ plugin and configure it to build with all source files. Please see [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac).

Comment: Thanks all ! 
Yes the issue was linked to answers of Someprogrammerdude & 273K

Answer (score 0):

VSCode isn't linking together your files it is only compiling the main file so it doesn't have the definition of `_areaRectangle`. You will need to edit the VSCode plugin settings to compile all the files in your project. There is probably a list argument in the launch config that lets you list all the files to compile together.

Do you have the files defined in your CMake config file? VSCode should be able to pick it up from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand that I have to modify the tasks.json to build multiple files. I've change de tasks.json by replacing `${file}` by `${workspaceFolder}/*.c`.

I think an error I was making previously, was to "Run Code" and not "Run C/C++ File". I still got the same error when I use "Run Code", but apparently not when I "Run C/C++ file" or "Debug C/C++ file". Does it make sense ? 

I'm not sure how to use CMake though, i'll have to dig into that.